# Abaqus Python getByBoundingBox: 6.10 vs 6.13+

Tags: python, bounding-box, abaqus

I have written a Python Script for ABAQUS to create several parts with many partitions. To get a structered mesh I have to select several edges. Now there is one edge I apparently cannot select in ABAQUS 6.10 & 6.11. Oddly, everything is fine with ABAQUS 6.13+.

```
p = mdb.models[name_model].parts[name_part_1]
e = p.edges
pickedEdges = e.getByBoundingBox(((cos(alpha_rad)*ri)-delta_p),((sin(alpha_rad)*ri)-delta_p),0.0,
                                 ((cos(alpha_rad)*d_core/2)+delta_p),((sin(alpha_rad)*d_core/2)+delta_p),0.0)
p.seedEdgeByBias(biasMethod=SINGLE, end2Edges=pickedEdges, ratio=bias_f, number=elem_num_rad, constraint=FINER)
```

Here, 'ri' is used to describe a radius, 'delta_p' (=0.001) is used to get a boundingbox slightly bigger than the original edge.

I also tried to use a bigger boundingbox by increasing delta_p but nothing works.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance! :)

for a sketch:
[click me](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/imageodm5h2pz84.jpg)

the described bounding box is box E and I try to get the orange line

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your post why the method isn't working. 
you could determine a point on your edge and use the findAt method instead of getByBoundingBox.

By setting delta_p to a very large number, you should select every edge in your model? Its not clear what you mean by "not working"

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer. 
Now I have added a sketch - see main post.
What isnt working: in ABAQUS 6.10 and 6.11 this bounding box will be empty and the orange line wont get any seeds, when executed in ABAQUS 6.13+ everything is fine and this line gets the right number of seeds to generete a structured mesh.

Comment: As mentioned above, the `findAt` method is probably safer to use across versions of Abaqus.

Comment: @freakxz, you have used 0.0 as your zmin and zmax, perhaps you should use -1.0 and +1.0